# How to skip a directory starting with a particular name?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have some directories sitting at

```
/home/ubuntu/ansible-environments/aws
```

inside this there are many sub-directories which follow the following convention:

```
/home/ubuntu/ansible-environments/aws/random_name1/inventory/group_vars/all
/home/ubuntu/ansible-environments/aws/random_name2/inventory/group_vars/all
/home/ubuntu/ansible-environments/aws/random_name3/inventory/group_vars/all
/home/ubuntu/ansible-environments/aws/random_name4/inventory/group_vars/all
/home/ubuntu/ansible-environments/aws/random_name5/inventory/group_vars/all
/home/ubuntu/ansible-environments/aws/TERMINATED_random_name1/inventory/group_vars/all
```

Now the following piece of code is able to get me all the directories inside the above folder, but i wanted to skip the TERMINATED part, how can i do so ?

```
outer_dir=os.path.expanduser("/home/ubuntu/ansible-environments/aws")
print (outer_dir)
random_names = os.listdir(outer_dir)
print (random_names)
inner_dirs = [
    os.path.join(outer_dir, name, "inventory/group_vars")

    for name in random_names
]
#print (inner_dirs)

# Now filter it to those directories that actually exist
inner_dirs = [name for name in inner_dirs if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

Comment: What's a "TERMINATED part"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter it out while creating the `inner_dirs` list:

```
inner_dirs = [
    os.path.join(outer_dir, name, "inventory/group_vars")
    for name in random_names
    if name[:10] != "TERMINATED"
]
```

Comment: what is [:10] mean?

Comment: Slice the first 10 characters from the string. Check: http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/

Comment: @Kittystone it gets the first 10 (0 through 10) characters of the string. So `"random_name5"[:10] == "random_nam"` and `"TERMINATED_random_name1"[:10] == "TERMINATED"`. It's identical to `name[0:10]`

Comment: You could also put both of your filters into the same list comprehension: `inner_dirs = [os.path.join(outer_dir, name, "inventory/group_vars") for name in random_names if name[:10] != "TERMINATED" if os.path.isdir(name)]`

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way would be:

```
if not name.startswith("TERMINATED")
```